# Array data smart merging with Php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach, merge

Basically i got an array with this kind of structure:

Array:

```
0 => {
    time: "090019"
    val: "2.444"
    qta: "292"
    dir: "up"
    param: "S"
}

1=>  {
    time: "090019"
    val: "2.442"
    qta: "938"
    dir: "dwn"
    param: "N"
}

2 =>  {
    time: "090019"
    val: "2.442"
    qta: "220"
    dir: "up"
    param: "N"
}

3 =>  {
    time: "100043"
    val: "2.44"
    qta: "220"
    dir: "dwn"
    param: "N"
}
```

.. so on and so forth

```
n =>  {
    time: "103051"
    val: "2.444"
    qta: "330"
    dir: "dwn"
    param: "N"
}
```

> **And my goal is to obtain an array with the same structure where data will be merged in a precise way.**

If two ore more array values have the same time (time) and value (val) they will be: added if they had same direction (dir), and subtracted if they don't (in this case the resulting direction will be the (dir) of the higher value). The param (param) is irrelevant.

I'm quite brand new with Php and I never know how to approach when I have to solve things like that.

Hoping to be sufficiently clear, any advice will be appreciated.

EDIT:

the resulting array will be like:

```
0 => {
    time: "090019"
    val: "2.444"
    qta: "292"
    dir: "up"
    param: "S"
}

1 =>  {
    time: "090019"
    val: "2.442"
    qta: "718"
    dir: "dwn"
    param: "N"
}

2 =>  {
    time: "100043"
    val: "2.44"
    qta: "220"
    dir: "dwn"
    param: "N"
}


..

n =>  {
    time: "103051"
    val: "2.444"
    qta: "330"
    dir: "dwn"
    param: "N"
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example with like five items in your initial array, and then what you want the result to look like?

Comment: What if you have three or four items that are the same?  How do you want to merge them?

Comment: If you have four items with the same time and val, you say you want to have them "added if they had same direction (dir), and subtracted if they don't" but how do you determine "same direction" when you have four direction values?  Do you mean all of the "up" dirs are added to the "down"?  Then which is subtracted from which?  Do you just mean an up is positive, a down is negative, and you add them all together?

Comment: Precisely! I mean an up is positive, a down is negative, and add them all together but at the end the number will be without sign and it will be 'up' if positive and 'dwn' if negative. My experience tell me that usually max 3 of them in a row could have the same time/val.

Comment: That may have been good information to include in the question  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a fun problem, so here's something that would probably work for you, out of the box  :)

First, define your items:

```
$items = array(

    array(
        "time" => "090019",
        "val" => "2.444",
        "qta" => "292",
        "dir" => "up",
        "param" => "S",
    ),

    array(
        "time" => "090019",
        "val" => "2.442",
        "qta" => "938",
        "dir" => "dwn",
        "param" => "N",
    ),

    array(
        "time" => "090019",
        "val" => "2.442",
        "qta" => "220",
        "dir" => "up",
        "param" => "N",
    ),

    array(
        "time" => "100043",
        "val" => "2.44",
        "qta" => "220",
        "dir" => "dwn",
        "param" => "N",
    ),

);
```

Next, iterate through the items array once to group items together based on the same time and val:

```
$grouped_items = array();

foreach($items as $item) {
    $key = "{$item['time']}-{$item['val']}";

    if( empty($grouped_items[$key]) ) $group_items[$key] = array();

    $grouped_items[$key][] = $item;
}
```

At this point, you have an array with keys equal to time-val.  Each of those is a subarray containing a list of all items matching that item-val (so you grouped together the same time/val items).  Finally, you can create your merged list:

```
$final_items = array();

foreach($grouped_items as $item_list) {
    $final_items[] = mergeItems($item_list);
}

// merge a list of items with the same time and val
function mergeItems($items) {
    $merged_item = array(
        "time" => $items[0]['time'],
        "val" => $items[0]['val'],
        "qta" => 0,
        "dir" => null,
        "param" => $items[0]['param'],
    );

    // add or subtract qta values
    foreach($items as $item) {
        if( $item['dir'] == "up" ) {
            $merged_item["qta"] += (int) $item["qta"];
        }
        else {
            $merged_item["qta"] -= (int) $item["qta"];
        }
    }

    // set the final qta and dir value
    if( $merged_item["qta"] < 0 ) {
        $merged_item["qta"] *= -1;
        $merged_item["dir"] = "down";
    }
    else {
        $merged_item["dir"] = "up";
    }

    return $merged_item;
}
```

Now $final_items has your merged list.

If you paste all of this into one PHP script, it'll run and give you the output you want.  If it doesn't do exactly what you want with your real data, then you forgot to mention something in your question and can probably use this example to create something that will work  :)

Comment: First of all thanks for the time you dedicate to it. Now, my purpose is to learn how to approach situation like this. Can you explain how does the first foreach loop work? is not clear to me..

Comment: @Plastic You want to find out which items in your list match, so that you can merge them.  The first foreach loops over the items and groups them together, based on matching times and vals.  It puts matching items together into little "sub arrays".

Comment: is this the command that create the little "sub arrays"?
$key = "{$item['time']}-{$item['val']}";
$group_items[$key] = array();
$grouped_items[$key][] = $item;
what does the first row means?

Comment: I'm creating a key that will be unique for that time/val combination.  Basically, any item with the same time/val will end up with the same key.  Then I check if it's already been created (e.g. if a previous iteration of the foreach loop already created it).  If not, I'll set that key in the array to be an empty array.  Then I append to it (if it's a new array, it will have just one item, if it was created in a previous iteration, it will have one more item).

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic answer where you can do what you want with the new qta:

```
$items = array([put your data here]);

for($i=0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j < count($items); $j++) {
        // don't compare and item to itself
        if($i == $j) continue;

        // if their times and values are equal
        if( $items[$i]["time"] == $items[$j]["time"] && $items[$i]["val"] == $items[$j]["val"]) {
            // dirs are the same
            if( $items[$i]["dir"] == $items[$j]["dir"] ) {
                $newqta = $items[$i]["qta"] + $items[$j]["qta"];
                $newdir = $items[$i]["dir"];
            }
            // dirs are different
            else {
                $newqta = $items[$i]["qta"] - $items[$j]["qta"];

                if( $items[$i]["qta"] > $items[$j]["qta"] ) {
                    $newdir = $items[$i]["dir"];
                }
                else {
                    $newdir = $items[$j]["dir"];
                }
            }

            // do something with $newqta and $newdir
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer. If two or more items will be added/subtracted what will be the value of 'dir' param for the resulting item?

Comment: What do you mean by added/subtracted?  What do you want added?  Or do you mean included/not included in the final array of data?

Comment: let's suppose items 2 and 3 are:
1=> { time: "090019" val: "2.44" qta: "938" dir: "dwn" param: "N" }

2 => { time: "090019" val: "2.44" qta: "220" dir: "up" param: "N" }

thet qta will be the result of 938 - 220 = 718 but the new item in the array will have dir='up' or 'dwn'? I want that will be 'dwn' cause 938 is greater..

Comment: @Plastic Just clarify your original question with an example.

Comment: my goal is to abtain a new array with the same structure and the merged data

Comment: @Plastic Yeah, this just gives you a start.  I don't think the purpose of stackoverflow is to write all of your programs for you  :)

Comment: I was asking to learn how to handle data merging in a way different from simply adding items value. Thanks for the answer, it worked!